# Best practice to keep permanent connection (like websockets) for real-time messaging on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, websocket, xamarin.android

I'm developing Android (with Xamarin) app for real-time messaging. There is a permanent websockets connection which is consume a lot of battery.

I also have push messages (firebase) for resume connection (start android service) when app is closed or device in Doze or screen is locked. But it does not completely solve my issue, because connection is consume a lot of energy as I wrote.

So, what is the best way to do permanent connection for real-time messaging?

Comment: Why don't go with `Firebase`?

Comment: Let's accept that Firebase does not appropriate solution or does not fit into the current app architecture...